# Force uppercase on some WooCommerce checkout fields input

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, javascript

I'm using this code to limit max number of characters to a determined field... is it possible to force UPPERCASE?

Here's what I'm using:

```
add_action("wp_footer", "cod_set_max_length");

function cod_set_max_length(){
    if( !is_checkout())
    return;
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#cracha_empresa").attr('maxlength','33');
        $("#cracha_primeironome").attr('maxlength','12');
        $("#cracha_sobrenome").attr('maxlength','26');
        // more fields
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple things.

Use JS `toUpperCase()` to transform the text.

```
var upper = text.toUpperCase();
```

Or just use CSS to do it.

```
#yourID {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```